# Slideshow that flows like a scroller

Tags: jquery-plugins, slideshow

Where can I find a slidseshow jquery plugin so that I can show the main slide and parts of its two siblings (previous and next)?

I searched for more than an hour and nothing seems to do it.

[Anythingslide](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#&panel1-1) seems to be close to it but I still need to find a way to set the left style of the list when moving the slides.

[SmoothScroller](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html#toc) only seems to handle images... We need to also display a caption below each image.

Answer (score 0):

Use this loopSlider

http://www.jboss.org/help/projectpageguide/imagestyleguide/loopedslider

Change some css and you will get the required result, read its documentations for further requirements.